# Getting error on In-App Subscription in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I'm setting up Google in-App subscripton (yearly) in the app. I have implemented the code into the MainActivity.class file in Android Studio.

I am able to get the purchase complete successfuly using the android.test.purchased product id. I uploaded the signed APK onto Play Console, create a subscription ID and input this subscription ID in place of android.test.purchased but I get the error that says "a problem has occurred on our end."

```
import com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor;
import com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.TransactionDetails;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler{
BillingProcessor bp;
bp = new BillingProcessor(this, null, this);
```

And to initialize the payment gateway, i use:

```
bp.purchase(MainActivity.this,"android.test.purchased");
```

The following methods have been implemented in the same class;

```
public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details){
    registered= 1;
}

public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored()
{

}

public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error)
{

}

public void onBillingInitialized() {

}
```

Could you please help me sort out this issue.